# What is the probability a person leaves via a certain exit?

Tags: probability

```
             | Exit 1 |             | Exit 4 |
             |        |             |        |
             |        |             |        |
             |        |             |        |
_____________|        |_____________|        |________

Exit 2           S1                    s2         Exit 6
_____________          _____________          ________
             |        |             |        |
             |        |             |        |
             |        |             |        |
             | Exit 3 |             | Exit 5 |
```

Hopefully the above diagram is clear. There are 6 exits. There is a bug that starts at S1, we equal probability he can go to Exit1, Exit2, Exit3, or s2. Once at S2, he can go to S1 Exit6, Exit5, Exit4 with equal probability. Once you go to an exit, you are no longer able to return and you are done. What is the probability the person leaves via Exit 6.

I've tried solving this with a markov matrix, but I think there is a simpler solution. Any hints / how to approach this more directly?

Comment: There are only two  active states, just consider what happens at $S_1, S_2$.

Comment: $3a+3b=1$, $a$ being the probability of leaving through exit 1, 2 or 3, $b$ 4, 5 or 6. And $a=1/4+b/4$, by symmetry.

Comment: $a = 1/4 + b/4$?

Comment: To leave through exit 1, you have a quarter chance to leave on first turn, plus the chance of going to S2 on first turn ($1/4$) and eventually leaving through exit 1, which is the odd of leaving through one of the doors of the opposite side, i.e. $b$.

Comment: I don't see that, what do you mean by: "which is the odd of leaving through one of the doors of the opposite side, i.e. b"

Comment: Assuming you went to S2 at the end of first turn, E1, E2 and E3 now have the law that E4, E5 and E6 had on the first turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i\in \{1,2\}$, let  $P_i$ denote the probability that you will  eventually leave by Exit $6$ given that you are currently in state $S_i$.  Thus $P_1$ is the answer you want.

We note that $$P_1=\frac 34\times 0 +\frac 14\times P_2\implies 4P_1=P_2$$

and  $$P_2=\frac 14\times 1 +\frac 12\times 0 +\frac 14\times P_1\implies 4P_2=1+P_1$$

this system is easily solved and yields $$\boxed {P_1=\frac 1{15}}$$.

Comment: Pretty simple solution...Thanks! How can I think of this in context of markov matrix? How did you see this solution?

Comment: $P(E_8|S_1) = \frac{1}{4}P(E_8|S_2)$ and $P(E_8|S_2) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}P(E_8|S_1)$ (just rewriting with some easier notation for me)

Comment: This is a pretty standard approach to Markov processes that have a small number of states.  You can see quickly that either you end the process after a couple moves or you find yourself back at the start.  That's all that the method says.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Markov matrix idea is quite simple and effective. Either raise it to a large power or look at its Eigenvalues and the steady-state should become quite clear.

Another option is to use a directed graph/network with 8 nodes but this would likely then lead to an adjacency matrix and be very similar to your Markov approach.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P_n$ be the probability of exiting by exit 6 in $n$ steps, $n$ must be even.

$$ P_2 = P(S_1 \to S_2)\times P(S_2 \to E_6) =\frac 1{16}$$

$$P_4 = P(S_1 \to S_2)\times P(S_2 \to S_1)\times P(S_1 \to S_2)\times P(S_2 \to E_6)= \frac 1{16} \times P_2$$

So the total probability of leaving by $E_6$ is given by the sum of the geometric series...

$$ P = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( \frac 1{16} \right )^k = \frac 1{15}
$$